# Dart Http Package request timeout

Tags: http, flutter, dart

While using `http` package in my flutter app, I encountered a slight issue. I am testing on localhost and when I post something in database using http.post, it doesn't return response for default time (i.e. 60s I think) when server is not running. And when I start the apache and mysql services within the timeout, it posts the data in the server . Is there any way to reduce the timeout of the http requests in dart http package? Or is there any alternative solution?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is for **[http](https://pub.dev/packages/http)** package

```
final response = await http.post(Url).timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));
```

And this is for **[Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)** package (recommend to test this package)

```
BaseOptions options = new BaseOptions(
    baseUrl: baseUrl,
    connectTimeout: Duration(milliseconde: 10000 ), //10 seconds
    receiveTimeout: Duration(milliseconde: 10000 ),
   );

Dio dio = new Dio(options);

Response<dynamic> response = await dio.post(url, data: mapData);
```

Answer (score 8):

You have two options availabe.

**Reduce the timeout on the HttpClient**

```
final client = new HttpClient();
client.connectionTimeout = const Duration(seconds: 10);
```

This will apply to all request made by the same client. If the request exceeds this timeout, a `SocketException` is thrown.

**Set a per request timeout**
You can set a timeout on any Future using the `Future.timeout` method.

```
try {
  ..
  final request = await client.get(...);
  final response = await request.close().timeout(const Duration(seconds: 10));
  // more code
} on TimeoutException catch (e) {
  // handle timeout
}
```